# c++ input error

Tags: c++

In this programme,during input, name and area fields are skipped.
I even tried gets() to enter string(name) but it still skips name after emp no.
In this programme,during input, name and area fields are skipped.
I even tried gets() to enter string(name) but it still skips name after emp no.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    using namespace std;
    struct addr
        {
            int houseno;
            char area[20];
            char city[20];
            char  state[20];
        };
    struct Emp
        {   
            int empno;
            char name[20];
            char desig[10];
            addr address;
            float basic;
        }worker;
    int main()
    {
        cout<<"Employee no: ";
        cin>>worker.empno;
        cout<<"Name: ";
        cin.getline(worker.name,20);
        cout<<"Designation: ";
        cin.getline(worker.desig,10);
        cout<<"Enter Address: "<<endl;
        cout<<"1. House no. :";
        cin>>worker.address.houseno;
        cout<<"2. Area: ";
        cin.getline(worker.address.area,20);
        cout<<"3. City: ";
        cin.getline(worker.address.city,20);
        cout<<"4. State: ";
        cin.getline(worker.address.state,20);
        cout<<"Basic Pay: ";
        cin>>worker.basic;
        cout<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to be taken seriously, remove the ALL CAPS from the title. It's generally interpreted like shouting in the internet community.

Comment: ok... thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting input of your integer variable you should use cin.ignore() for your getline() function.
Here is your corrected version

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
struct addr
{
    int houseno;
    char area[20];
    char city[20];
    char  state[20];
};
struct Emp
{
    int empno;
    char name[20];
    char desig[10];
    addr address;
    float basic;
}worker;
int main()
{
    cout << "Employee no: ";
    cin >> worker.empno;
    cin.ignore(); //use it
    cout << "Name: ";
    cin.getline(worker.name, 20);
    cout << "Designation: ";
    cin.getline(worker.desig, 10);
    cout << "Enter Address: " << endl;
    cout << "1. House no. :";
    cin >> worker.address.houseno;
    cin.ignore(); //because houseno is also integer
    cout << "2. Area: ";
    cin.getline(worker.address.area, 20);
    cout << "3. City: ";
    cin.getline(worker.address.city, 20);
    cout << "4. State: ";
    cin.getline(worker.address.state, 20);
    cout << "Basic Pay: ";
    cin >> worker.basic;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```